# Is it possible to have 2 scripts in PYTHONSTARTUP?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda

I will preface this by saying I am very limited in my Python knowledge. My team wanted me to research if it is possible to have 2 scripts in your PYTHONSTARTUP.

Currently, we have a startup script DIT_startup.py that runs on Python boot, as it should.

```
echo $PYTHONSTARTUP
/usr/app/utils/python/ditStartup.py
```

Is it possible to add a second script in there (a la how you can add multiple references in PATH separated with ;)

The reason we are wanting to do this is, let's say our uses want to create their own PYTHONSTARTUP with some extras, we were hoping they could just add a 2nd on in. (i.e ditStartup.py and Rob_CUSTOMSSTARTUP.py) and someone else would have (ditStartup.py and MIKE_CUSTOMSTARTUP.py)

I guess we could in theory have them add their extra commands to the dit_startup.py (the script we are now using), but for troubleshooting purposes I would like the file to stay universally the same/untouched, and keep the differences separated.

I tried Googling/searching StackOverflow and can't really find this mentioned, so I'm worried it's not possible.

---

If it matters:
We are using both 2.7 and 3.4 (but are using Anaconda) and we are on RHEL 6.7 - although it seems like PYTHONSTARTUP doesn't change much over different versions/years.

Comment: Write a script that imports 2 scripts that you've already made.

Comment: It works that simply? 

I was thinking that (similar to how you can call multiple .bats in one overall .bat on Windows)

Thanks! That's great that, it's that easy!